# How do I track multiple domain in Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I have 2 unrelated websites with different content.

- `mydomain1.com`
- `mydomain2.com`

I already have a Google Analytics account for `http://mydomain1.com`. Now I want to add my second domain `http://mydomain2.com` to my analytics account. I want to view separate report for different domains.

Now how should I add my second domain as **New Account** or **New Property**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a new property to the existing Account. Account comes topmost in the hierarchy. It contains multiple properties. Properties are individual sites you want to monitor. Each will have its own tracking code so each will generate its own stats.
You can also add an account for each, but that would be overkill.

Refer here: https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1009618&topic=1102143&ctx=topic

Answer (score 0):

**New property** of the existing **account**. Use an **account** to file under all the related **properties**.

By the way, you can read the [GA API Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/) ;)